# How to explain the result of tf.map_fn?

Tags: tensorflow

Look at the code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = tf.ones([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64)
alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: (x, x, x), elems, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(alternates))
```

The output is:

```py
(array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]], dtype=int64), array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]], dtype=int64), array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]], dtype=int64))
```

I can't understand the output, who can tell me?

### update

`elems` is a tensor, so it should be unpacked along axis-0, and we will get `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]`, and then `map_fn` pass `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]` into `lambda x:(x,x,x)`,which means `x=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]`, and I think the output of `map_fn` is

```py
[[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
 [[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
 [[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]]
```

The shape of output is `[3,2,3]` or a list of `shape(2,3)`

But in fact, the output is a list of tensor, the shape of each tensor is `[1,2,3]`.

Or in other words:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64)
alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: (x, 2*x, -x), elems, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(alternates))
```

Why the output is

```py
(array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64), 
 array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int64), 
 array([-1, -2, -3], dtype=int64))
```

rather than

```py
(array([1, 2, -1], dtype=int64), 
 array([2, 4, -2], dtype=int64), 
 array([3, 6, -3], dtype=int64))
```

The two question is the same.

### Update2

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = [tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64)]
alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, elems, dtype=tf.int64)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(alternates))
```

`elems` is a list of tensor, so according to api, `tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64)` will be unpacked along axis-0, so `map_fn` will works as `[x for x in [1,2,3]]`, but in fact it will raise a error.

```py
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure. First struc
ture: <dtype: 'int64'>, second structure: [<tf.Tensor 'map/while/TensorArrayRead
V3:0' shape=() dtype=int64>].
```

What's wrong?

### update3

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = (tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64))
alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, elems, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(alternates))
```

The output is

```py
(array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64))
```

It seems that elems aren't unpacked, why?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = (tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64))
alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: [x], elems, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(alternates))
```

It will raise a error

```py
TypeError: The two structures don't have the same sequence type. First structure
 has type <class 'tuple'>, while second structure has type <class 'list'>.
```

Who can tell me how tf.map_fn works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First,

```py
elems = tf.ones([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64)
```

`elems` is a 3-dimensional tensor with shape 1x2x3 full of ones, that is:

```py
[[[1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]]]
```

Then,

```py
alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: (x, x, x), elems, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64))
```

`alternates` is a tuple of three tensors with the same shape as `elems`, each of which is built according to the given function. Since the function simply returns a tuple repeating its input three times, that means that the three tensors will be the same as `elems`. If the function were `lambda x: (x, 2 * x, -x)` then the first output tensor would be the same as `elems`, the second would be the double of `elems` and the third one the opposite.

In all these cases it is preferable to use regular operations instead of [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn); however, there may be cases where you have a function accepting tensors with *N* dimensions and you have a tensor with *N* + 1 that you want to have it applied to.

*UPDATE:*

I think you are thinking of [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) "the other way around", so to say. There is not a one-to-one correspondence between the number of elements or rows in the tensor and the number of outputs in the function; in fact, you could pass a function returning a tuple with as many elements as you want.

Taking your last example:

```py
elems = tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64)
alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: (x, 2*x, -x), elems, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64))
```

[`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) first split `elems` in the first axis, that is into `1`, `2` and `3`, and applies the function to each of them, getting:

```py
(1, 2, -1)
(2, 4, -2)
(3, 6, -3)
```

Note that, as I said, each of these tuples could have as many elements as you wanted. Now, the final output is produced concatenating the results **in the same position**; so you get:

```py
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 6]
[-1, -2, -3]
```

Again, if the function produced tuples with more elements you would get more output tensors.

*UPDATE 2:*

About your new example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

elems = (tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64))
alternates = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, elems, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(alternates))
```

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) says:

> This method also allows multi-arity elems and output of fn. If elems is a (possibly nested) list or tuple of tensors, then each of these tensors must have a matching first (unpack) dimension. The signature of fn may match the structure of elems. That is, if elems is (t1, [t2, t3, [t4, t5]]), then an appropriate signature for fn is: fn = lambda (t1, [t2, t3, [t4, t5]]):.

Here `elems` is a tuple of two tensors with the same size in the first dimension, as needed. [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) takes one element of each input tensor at a time (so a tuple of two elements) and applies the given function to it, which should return the same structure that you passed in `dtypes` (a tuple of two elements, too); if you don't give a `dtypes`, then the expected output is the same as the input (again, a tuple of two elements, so in your case `dtypes` is optional). Anyway, it goes like this:

```py
f((1, 1)) -> (1, 1)
f((2, 2)) -> (2, 2)
f((3, 3)) -> (3, 3)
```

These results are combined, concatenating all the corresponding elements in the  structure; in this case, all the numbers in the first position produce the first output and all the numbers in the second positions produce the second output. The result is, finally, the requested structure (the two-element tuple) filled with these concatenations:

```py
([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Look at my commit on @GPhilo, passing a tensor, it isn't unpacked.

Comment: I'm still confused, look at the update3, can you tell me more details?

Comment: @gaussclb I have updated with further explanations for your last example.

Answer (score 1):

Your input `elems` have **shape** `(1,2,3)` and look like this:

```py
[[[1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1]]]
```

It's **not** a matrix containing values `1,2,3`, because you create it with `tf.ones()` that makes a tensor filled with `1` with the shape you pass as parameter

### Replying to the Update:

`map_fn` is applied to `elems` itself.
According to [`tf.map_fn`'s documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

> elems: A tensor or (possibly nested) sequence of tensors, each of which will be unpacked along their first dimension. The nested sequence of the resulting slices will be applied to fn.

From what I understand there, the function expects a tensor or a **list of tensors** and supposedly slices it and applies the function to each element. However, from the results it seems that if you pass in a tensor that's the element it applies the function to directly, so `x` has shape `(1,2,3)` when the lambda function is called.
The function then creates a tuple with 3 copies of your `(1,2,3)` matrix (which is the `array(...)` in your output)

Restructuring the output line and adding indent to make it more clear, the output looks as follows:

```py
( 
   array( # first copy of `x`
       [
           [
               [1, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1]
           ]
       ], dtype=int64
   ), 
   array( # second copy of `x`
       [
           [
               [1, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1]
           ]
       ], dtype=int64
   ), 
   array( # third copy of `x`
       [
           [
               [1, 1, 1],
               [1, 1, 1]
           ]
       ], dtype=int64
   ), 
) # end of the tuple
```

### Update 2:

<s>My suspicion is that you ran into a bug. If you define elems as a list, you have the error, but if you define it as a `tuple` with `elems = (tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64))`, the code works as expected. Different handling of tuples and lists is very suspicious... which is why I believe it's a bug.</s>
As @mrry pointed out, in my example with the tuple I missed a comma (and thus elems was the tensor itself and not a tuple containing the tensor).

Comment: You are right, but I have another question, look at my update.

Comment: but the array's shape  of output is (1,2,3) not (2,3)

Comment: I realised. `map_fn` is supposed to operate on a list of tensors, I'm checking what happens when a tensor is passed instead

Comment: Perfect, if passing a tensor as elems, it shouldn't be unpacked, so I can understand the second of my question, because x=[1,2,3](aren't unpacked), and then return (x,2x,-x) so the output is  (array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),  array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int64), array([-1, -2, -3], dtype=int64)). Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome, although it's weird because reading the [`tf.map_fn` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) I also understand that the tensor should be sliced as you were expecting

Comment: Nit on Update 2: `elems = (tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64))` doesn't assign a tuple to `elems`, and it is the same as `elems = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int64)`. To make a tuple you need an extra comma, as follows: `elems = (tf.constant([1,2,3],dtype=tf.int64),)`.

Comment: But why will update2 raise a error? I think it should work well according to api doc. @mrry,GPhilo