# Tensorflow Type error when trying to iterate the Tensors in loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following scenario:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1],name="output")
layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, name="layer"+str(layer))
         for layer in range(2)]
multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, 100]) 
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, 1)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, 2, 1])
outputs = tf.identity(outputs[:,1,:], name="prediction")
loss = Custom_loss(y,outputs)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss,name="training_op")
```

The custom loss function I tried is:

```
def Custom_loss(y,outputs):
    hold_loss = []
    for exp,pred in zip(y,outputs):
        if exp >= pred:
            result = tf.pow(pred * 0.5,2) - exp
            hold_loss.append(result)
        else:
            hold_loss.append(tf.subtract(pred-exp))
    return tf.reduce_mean(hold_loss)
```

Now when I am trying to implement this I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

I have tried implementing the `tf.map_fn()` but there is the same error I encounter. I have used the following question:
[How to explain the result of tf.map_fn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096767/how-to-explain-the-result-of-tf-map-fn)

Kindly, help me get through this issue? How I can iterate the tensor? What way is best for the custom loss function implementation?

Comment: Is there someone please let me know what  can do?

Comment: Just add tf.enable_eager_execution() and it will run fine

Comment: @SiddharthDas This I know. But please can you see that I am using Placeholders and I cannot keep constant values so your suggestion won't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Custom_loss(y,outputs):
    mask = tf.greater_equal(y, outputs)
    a = tf.pow(tf.boolean_mask(outputs, mask)*0.5, 2) - tf.boolean_mask(y, mask)
    inv_mask = tf.logical_not(mask)
    b = tf.boolean_mask(outputs, inv_mask)- tf.boolean_mask(y, inv_mask)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.concat([a, b], axis=-1))
```

### Test case

```
def Custom_loss_np(y,outputs):
    hold_loss = []
    for exp,pred in zip(y,outputs):
        if exp >= pred:
            result = pow(pred * 0.5,2) - exp
            hold_loss.append(result)
        else:
            hold_loss.append(pred-exp)
    return np.mean(hold_loss)

np_x = np.random.randn(100)
np_y = np.random.randn(100)

x = tf.constant(np_x)
y = tf.constant(np_y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   assert sess.run(Custom_loss(x, y)) == Custom_loss_np(np_x, np_y)
```

Use `tf.math` if you are in latest versoin of tensorflow.

### Example using the custom loss to train a simple linear regression model

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])

w = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,1]))
y_ = tf.matmul(X, w)+b
loss = Custom_loss(y, y_) #tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y)) 

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss,name="training_op")

#dummy data for linear regression
x_data = np.random.randn(100,1)
y_labels = 1.5*x_data + 2.5 + np.random.randn(100,1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(5000):
    _, loss_ = sess.run([training_op,loss], feed_dict={X:x_data, y:y_labels})
    if (i+1)%1000 == 0 :
        print (loss_)

print (sess.run([w, b]))
```

The logic for calculating the loss is something OP have come up with.

Comment: But the custom function is not a part of the graph. I want that the custom function should be a part of the learning process?

Comment: `loss = Custom_loss(y,outputs)` and optimizing over loss should make it part of the graph.

Comment: But it did not worked. as you see in the question, I have mentioned what the graph I am trying to achieve and what is the matter I am facing the issue with.

Comment: did you got what issue I am talking about. i you need some more explanation please ask me. I will let you know.

Comment: Is there anything that you I can do to achieve what I wanted? Please do suggest.

Comment: @JafferWilson added an example on how to use it. Hope it helps

Comment: I can understand `Custom_loss` function but what if I want to implement the custom loss function using loop and conditions as I have mentioned? I know this `Custom_loss` is helpful for sure. But what if I needed to add different conditions and even truncate the loop is not required. Thats why I was expecting answer in the format of loop and condition. I am not able to loop through Tensors.

Comment: Can I use `Custom_loss_np` instead of `Custom_loss`?

Comment: @JafferWilson NO you cannot. For operations on tensors you have use tensor methods (ops) not numpy methods. Loops and conditions dont work on computation graphs in tensorflow, you have to use equivalent tensor ops for it.